# Play local mp3 with HTML5. How could save file reference to create a playlist?

Tags: html, filesystems, mp3, local

I am trying to write a mp3 player using HTML 5 benefits. Play local file, until now, seems ok. Im writing sample codes based on these example : http://antimatter15.github.com/player/player.html
Here's the thing : I have to get the reference of each mp3 file. I want to get all this reference and save on database for when the client access the website i show this playlists. The problem is : doing in that way I mentioned before every time that client close/open browser the blob reference to file is not valid anymore. Iam looking for FileSystem API, that allows to save data into sandbox section. So, data could be cleaned every time users wanted and im still cant save mp3 references on my server database. Could you guys give me sugestions? The real thing is just save a reference from mp3 local file to allow my user create a playlist and every time that he access the web page he could see that playlists.

Thanks in advance,

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this reference(or "object URLs") persistence thing is intentionally unsupported by the browsers. Otherwise you could access the user's filesystem without his awareness. This could be a security problem.

As quoted at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications):

> Each time you call window.URL.createObjectURL() , a unique object URL is created, even if you've created an object URL for that file already.